# Override framework file vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

Any one know how to override vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php file in M-2.3 ?

Tried:

```
1) Add class using XML:  failed
2) Created plugin to override the function: failed.
3) Created module and override using preference: failed
4) Created patch and override the file: failed.
```

Here we are overriding protected method(_toHtml()) which is not possible by plugin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve by change/override framework file? You may have other options as well?

Comment: I want to add class for each customer account left navigations so that I can add icon for each navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

add this to di.xml of your module

```
 <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" />
```

Then create the class
   [Vendor][Module]\View\Element\Html\Link\Current that extends
   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current and make your
   changes in there

Comment: As mentioned earlier, it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

As above all above I have tried was not working so added class by js like:
iterated the all li element then get the text and set it to class and used same class to add css changes.

If anyone find better answer please update.